# Use a Switch case or If else statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement, nullable

I am trying to calculate some angles depending on some 3d coordinates which use some odd axis (sometimes down is +ve , sometimes right is -ve etc) and have come up with the following switch case structure

```
    private double RobOrientX(double robY, double robZ)
    {
        double AngleX;

        switch (robY)
        {
            case robY>0:
                switch (robZ)
                {
                    case robZ>0:
                        AngleX = Math.Atan2(robZ,robY);
                        break;

                    case robZ<0:
                        AngleX = 360 + Math.Atan2(robZ, robY);
                        break;

                    case robZ=0:
                        AngleX = 0;
                        break;
                }
                break;

            case robY<0:
                switch (robZ)
                {
                    case robZ>0:
                        AngleX = 180 + Math.Atan2(robZ, robY);
                        break;

                    case robZ<0:
                        AngleX = 180 + Math.Atan2(robZ, robY);
                        break;

                    case robZ=0:
                        AngleX = 180;
                        break;
                }
                break;

            case robY=0:
                switch (robZ)
                {
                    case robZ>0:
                        AngleX = 90;
                        break;

                    case robZ<0:
                        AngleX = 270;
                        break;

                    case robZ=0:
                        AngleX = 0;
                        break;

                }
                break;
        }

        return AngleX;
    }
```

However there is an error on `switch (robY)` stating a switch expression needs to use a nullable type, of which I believed double was.

There are no errors on `switch (robZ)`. Is there something I am missing here or should I change it all to a series of If else statements?

Many Thanks

Comment: you can not have conditional expressions in case, you can have only constants

Comment: you can make double nullable like so: "double? robY"

Comment: You appear to be mixing degrees and radians... is that intentional? i.e. `180 + Math.Atan2(...)`

Comment: no I will create a quick method to convert them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with nullable values, and incidentally `double` is not nullable (`double?` is nullable). The problem is that in C# `case` statements must use constants, not boolean tests. You probably just want to use an `if`/`else` block.

```
if(robX > 0)
{
     //...
}
else if (robX < 0)
{
    //...
}
else if (robX == 0)
{
    //...
}
else
{
    // NaN etc?
}
```

Unrelated, but most math functions (including `Math.Atan2`) talk in *radians* - but you seem to be mixing them with degrees. This will have very odd results. 180 degrees is `Math.PI` radians.

Comment: thanks I will create a version using if else and convert the radians to degrees